# Search in array for pairs

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a array of `int`, size is `8`. What I want to do is search through `array` for pairs (eg. if number on index 0 is same as number on index `5`).

I tried make two arrays (second was copy of first) but that did not make sense because everything will be in pairs.

Then I tried to make half-array, so I made two `arrays` of size `4` and compare them. This didn't solve that the pairs can be in single array.

To fill `array` I am using random numbers, max value of random number is size of `array` `(8)`.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're after specific matches (in which case I'd expect index 5 rather than 4) or just *any* duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ.

```
int[] array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 };
var duplicates = array
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
foreach (var d in duplicates)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small max value, you can initialize a bit array of this length. Go through your original array and set the appropriate bit array for every member. If the bit array in this position is true, then you have a pair. If you want the specific position, use int array.
Try something like this:

```
BitArray bucket = new BitArray(<<your max value>>);
foreach(int i in originalArray)
{
if(bucket[i]) return true;
bucket[i] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to get not only list of values, that are duplicated, but also indexes where that values occurred you can use that LINQ to Objects query:

```
int[] items = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 7 };

var duplicates = items.Select((e, i) => new { e, i })
                      .GroupBy(i => i.e)
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Indexes = g.Select(e => e.i).ToList() })
                      .ToList();
```

`duplicates` contains 2 elements, with following content:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary (like *dict[i]==>array of indexes*)

```
var dubs = array.Select((i, inx) => new { i, inx })
            .GroupBy(x => x.i)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(y => y.inx).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to find pairs is to sort the array (Method A, below). Another way is to have two nested loops (Method B).

```
Tell("Method A...");
int[] a = new int[]{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 5, 5};
int lengthA = a.Length;
Array.Sort(a);
for (int i = 1; i < lengthA; i++)
{
  if (a[i-1] == a[i])
  {
    Tell("Method A Found pair in a: "+a[i-1]+" and "+a[i]);
  }
} // for i

Tell("Method B...");
int[] b = new int[]{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 5, 5};
int lengthB = b.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < lengthB-1; i++)
{
  for (int j = i+1; j < lengthB; j++)
  {
    if (b[i] == b[j])
    {
      Tell("Method B Found a pair in b: "+b[i]+" and "+b[j]);
    }
  } // for j
} // for i
```

Here is the output...

- Method A...
- Method A Found pair in a: 1 and 1
- Method A Found pair in a: 5 and 5
- Method A Found pair in a: 5 and 5
- Method B...
- Method B Found a pair in b: 1 and 1
- Method B Found a pair in b: 5 and 5
- Method B Found a pair in b: 5 and 5
- Method B Found a pair in b: 5 and 5

I hope you can see why Method B reports more pairs than Method A.